# SQL Server get data types for each column in a select statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a proc that uses a temp table and then at the end inserts into that from a select statement. I'm getting the following error:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric
```

Is there a way that I can find out what data type the select statement is using for the columns so I can compare that to the temp table definition so I can see what column(s) may be having the issue?

I guess another way to put it, how can I tell which records are causing this problem? I figured if I could get the data type in each column in the select statement and compare to the temp table then it would help lead me to finding the issue.

Comment: Uh, sure... e.g. Look at the data type in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` for whatever column you're selecting.

Comment: Try `sp_describe_first_result_set`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql

Comment: may be you can try using try and catch block to get details about the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below query will give the results

```
SELECT 
    c.name 'Column Name',
    t.Name 'Data type',
    c.max_length 'Max Length',
    c.precision ,
    c.scale ,
    c.is_nullable,
    ISNULL(i.is_primary_key, 0) 'Primary Key'
FROM    
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
WHERE
    c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('TableName')
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're trying to squeeze a number greater than 99999.99 into your decimal fields. You need to increase the number of digits before the decimal. You can do this by increasing the precision (which is the total number of digits before and after the decimal).

You can test this by commenting out the insert #temp and see what numbers the select statement is giving you and see if they are bigger than your column can handle.

Comment: How to quickly find that data is what I was looking for. I have 1200 records so it would be nice if there were a quick way to have a query point out the records that are causing the error.